# How to get and External IP for MongoDB in Openshift 3?

Tags: mongodb, routes, openshift, auth0, portforwarding

I have an app up and running in the Community version of Openshift 3 (hosted by them) and I need a way to connect directly (without port forwarding) to my mongoDB Service, to work with Auth0 user management.

I've tried to create a LoadBalancer, as suggested by some, but it doesn't solve the issue. It stays like this:

```
NAME              CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
mongodb-ingress   172.30.155.195   <pending>     27017:31556/TCP   1h
```

Creating a Route doesn't help either, as the only open port on this route is 80 (only seems to accepts http requests)

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: When you say 'Community' version, do you mean OpenShift Online Starter version?

Comment: Correct: OpenShift Online Starter

Comment: What do you get for ``oc get service yourservicename -o yaml``? It is quite possible that Starter doesn't allow you to expose services other than over HTTP via a route.

Comment: apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2017-09-26T07:48:12Z
  labels:
    app: mongodb-persistent
    template: mongodb-persistent-template
  name: mongodb-ingress
  namespace: a-dos-trancos
  resourceVersion: "48212608"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/a-dos-trancos/services/mongodb-ingress
  uid: 0bea17ca-a28f-11e7-9fab-02d8407159d1
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.30.155.195
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31556
    port: 27017
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    name: mongodb
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

Comment: Feedback I have confirms that neither OpenShift Online Starter or Pro support being able to expose non HTTP services. The only exception to this is if your application can terminate a secure TLS connection, the client for your application supports SNI with a TLS connection and you use a passthrough route such that the secure connection gets passed through to the application to terminate.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GrahamDumpleton. I unfortunately reached he same conclusion.